# Add values for keys that contains similar string in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value, defaultdict

I have dict as

```
values={'P-ETH-900':Decimal(122),'P-ETH-700':Decimal(455),'P-BTC-900':Decimal(12),'P-BTC-700':Decimal(55)}
```

I want to add the decimals that has condition like

```
eth=Decimal(0)
for i,j in values.items():
   if 'ETH' in i:
      eth=eth+j
```

So basically, for each similar items , need to sum up the decimal values.

output:

```
{'ETH':'577','BTC':'67'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension that calls `sum()`:

```
result = {currency: sum(v for k, v in values.items() if currency in k) for currency in ['ETH', 'BTC']}
```

Or you can use a `defaultdict` to extract the currency from the keys, assuming it's always the second component.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)

for key, value in values.items():
    result[key.split('-')[1]] += value
```

Comment: Can it be more dynamic without mentioning for currency in ?

Comment: Way ahead of you

Comment: @Barmar for your one-liner dictionary comprehension, you it should be `{currency: sum...` instead of `currency, sum...`

Comment: the second component is doing the work, is there any way in first component without mentioning currency as static ones @Barmar

Comment: You can get the currencies from the `values` dictionary: `currencies = set(key.split('-')[1] for key in values)`